# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') Todo List

Tags: reactjs

```js
useEffect(() => {
  //Get Value from Db
  const todo = collection(db, 'Todos');
  const todoSnapshot = getDocs(todo);
  const todoList = todoSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
  console.log(todoList);
  setTodo(todoList);
}, [input]);
```

encountering error in `todoSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());`

Comment: Well, `todoSnapshot.docs` is undefined...

Comment: What is the code of your getDocs function ? Consider writing that also .

Answer (score 0):

you need to await your request and set a loader whenever you will get API response first the loader will running then you will get the response.
map is not worked because it will receive a empty array of object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).